# Java - String splitting

Tags: java, string, split

I read a txt with data in the following format: Name Address Hobbies

Example(Bob Smith ABC Street Swimming)

and Assigned it into `String z`

Then I used `z.split` to separate each field using " " as the delimiter(space) but it separated `Bob Smith` into two different strings while it should be as one field, same with the address. Is there a method I can use to get it in the particular format I want?

P.S Apologies if I explained it vaguely, English isn't my first language.

```
String z;
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("desc.txt"));
    z = br.readLine();
} catch(IOException io) { 
    io.printStackTrace();
}
String[] temp = z.split(" ");
```

Comment: "*Is there a method i can use to get it in the particular format i want?*" - Use a different delimiter.

Comment: There is no algorithm that can know what is the name or address. As Turing85 said, use different delimiter like ";"

Comment: I understand that's an option but lets say I can't edit the txt file to make the separation character different such as ","(comma)

Comment: Then I would say you have a challenging task at hand. There is a good reason we separate different parts of an receiver's address by linebreaks when writing letters.

Answer (score 2):

If the format of `name` and `address` parts is fixed to consist of two parts, you could just join them:

```
String z = "";  // z must be initialized

// use try-with-resources to ensure the reader is closed properly
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("desc.txt"))) {
    z = br.readLine();
} catch(IOException io) { 
    io.printStackTrace();
}

String[] temp = z.split(" ");

String name = String.join(" ", temp[0], temp[1]);
String address = String.join(" ", temp[2], temp[3]);
String hobby = temp[4];
```

Another option could be to create a format string as a regular expression and use it to parse the input line using named groups `(?<group_name>capturing text)`:

```java
// use named groups to define parts of the line
Pattern format = Pattern.compile("(?<name>\\w+\\s\\w+)\\s(?<address>\\w+\\s\\w+)\\s(?<hobby>\\w+)");
Matcher match = format.matcher(z);
if (match.matches()) {
    String name = match.group("name");
    String address = match.group("address");
    String hobby = match.group("hobby");
    System.out.printf("Input line matched: name=%s address=%s hobby=%s%n", name, address, hobby);
} else {
    System.out.println("Input line not matching: " + z);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of three solutions.

In order from best to worst:

1. Different delimiter
2. Enforce the format to always have two names, two address parts and one hobby
3. Have a dictionary with names and hobbies, check each word to determine which type it is and then group them together as needed.

(The 3rd option is not meant as a serious alternative.)

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, using spaces as both field delimiter and inside fields is problematic. You could use a regex pattern to split the line (paste `(\w+ \w+) (\w+ \w+) (.+)` in [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) for an explanation):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+ \\w+) (\\w+ \\w+) (.+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("Bob Smith ABC Street Bowling Fishing Rollerblading");

System.out.println("matcher.matches() = " + matcher.matches());

for (int i = 0; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println("matcher.group(" + i + ") = " + matcher.group(i));
}
```

This would give the following output:

```
matcher.matches() = true
matcher.group(0) = Bob Smith ABC Street Bowling Fishing Rollerblading
matcher.group(1) = Bob Smith
matcher.group(2) = ABC Street
matcher.group(3) = Bowling Fishing Rollerblading
```

However this only works for this exact format. If you get a line with three name parts for example:

```
John B Smith ABC Street Swimming
```

This will get split into `John B` as the name, `Smith ABC` as the address and `Street Swimming` as hobbies.

So either make 100% sure your input will always match this format or use a different delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

The `split()` method majorly works on the 2 things:

- **Delimiter** and
- **The String Object**
- Sometimes on **limit** too.

Whatever limit you will provide, the `split()` method will do its work according to that.
It doesn't understand whether the left substring is a name or not, same as for the right substring.

**Have a look at this code snippet:**

```
String assets = "Gold:Stocks:Fixed Income:Commodity:Interest Rates";
String[] splits = assets.split(":");

System.out.println("splits.size: " + splits.length);

for(String asset: splits){
  System.out.println(assets);
}

OutPut

splits.size: 5
Gold
Stocks
Fixed Income         // with space
Commodity
Interest Rates       // with space
```

The output came with **spaces** because I provided the `;` as a delimiter.
This probably helped you to get your answer.

**Find Detailed Information on Split():**

[image: Split() Method in Java]

- [Top 5 Use cases of Split()](https://shubhamklogic.com/how-to-use-split-in-java-a-modern-guide/)
- [Java Docs : Split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the data you're dealing with.  Will the name always consist of a first and last name?  Then you can simply combine the first two elements from the resulting array into a new string.

Otherwise, you might have to find a different way to separate out the different pieces within the txt file.  Possibly a comma?  Some character that you know won't ever be used in your normal data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every line follows the format

> Bob Smith ABC Street Swimming

ie, name surname.... this code can manually manipulate the data for you:

```
        String[] temp = z.split(" ");
        String[] temp2 = new String[temp.length - 1];
        temp2[0] = temp[0] + " " + temp[1];
        for (int i = 2; i < temp.length; i++) {
            temp2[i] = temp2[i];
        }
        temp = temp2;
```